# zipalign error : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, apk, alignment

I type in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>zipalign  [-f] [-v]
B10816062011-unaligned.apk B10816062011-aligned.apk

it returns:

The system cannot find the file specified.

Its driving me crazy as I know that the source file is where I am trying to direct it!

anyone know or experienced this problem?

Comment: Type complete path of B10816062011-unaligned.apk

Comment: its ok I resolved it. I ran: zipalign -v 4 source.apk destination.apk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please avoid the [](Square Brackets) and <>

For example:

```
D:\android-sdk\android-sdk\tools>zipalign -f -v 4 "C:\Users\name\Desktop\project_name\projectname_signed.apk" "C:\Users\name\Desktop\project_name\projectname__zipaligned.apk"
```

It will work

Comment: Thanks I was using command from Android Developer they had brackets.

  zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk

Answer (score 1):

Also do not forget to look into the firewall on your computer. it may have been set to block the zipalign process.